# Adding Text on UI with SVG

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

I have added a text on my UI using g element with svg. However, I am stuck to put another text on UI. Is there a way instead of copy and paste the following code to duplicate another text?

```
        var legendData = [{ color: "white", text: "MyData" }];
        var legends = svg.selectAll("g legends").data(legendData);
        var legendBox = legends.enter()
             .append("g")

        legendBox.append("text")
           .attr("dx", function (d) { return 20 })
           .attr("dy", function (d) { return 15 })
           .text(function (d) { return d.text })
           .attr("stroke", "white")



        // is it right way ????
        var legendData2 = [{ color: "white", text: "MyData2" }];
        var legends2 = svg.selectAll("g legends").data(legendData2);
        var legendBox2 = legends.enter()
             .append("g")

        legendBox2.append("text")
           .attr("dx", function (d) { return 20 })
           .attr("dy", function (d) { return 15 })
           .text(function (d) { return d.text })
           .attr("stroke", "white")
```

Comment: If you want a second element, add a second datum to your data.

Comment: I have updated my question. Is that good way to do it?

Comment: No, just use `[{ color: "white", text: "MyData" }, { color: "white", text: "MyData" }]` as data.

Comment: That is actually what I thought. However I do not know where/ how to define the coordinates of each data?

Comment: Just add more attributes in the data.

Comment: Sorry, Lars still I could not able to get your point. I am quite new on this environment.

Comment: Well something like `{ color: "white", text: "MyData", dx: 20, dy: 15}` and similarly for the other datum.

Comment: Thanks Lars I think now I have got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sum up based on Lars comments:

```
var legendData = [{ color: "white", text: "MyData", dx: 20, dy: 15 }, 
                  { color: "white", text: "MyData2", dx: 20, dy: 25 }, 
                  { color: "white", text: "MyData3", dx: 20, dy: 35 }];

    var legends = svg.selectAll("g legends").data(legendData);
    var legendBox = legends.enter()
         .append("g")

    legendBox.append("text")
       .attr("dx", function (d) { return 20 })
       .attr("dy", function (d) { return 15 })
       .text(function (d) { return d.text })
       .attr("stroke", "white")
```